# Question regarding proof Riesz Frechet theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading the proof of the riesz frechet theorem, and the writer assumed something which i don't quite understand:

Theorem: Let H be hilbert and $f \in H'$, then we can find a unique $y$ such that $f(x) = (x,y)$ and $||f|| = 1$.

so if $f(x) = 0$ we can just take $y = 0$, so lets look at the other situation and look at the kernel, then since the kernel is a closed subspace of the hilbert space we know $ker(f)^{\bot} \neq \{0\}$.

Now i don't see why the following statement is true:

since $ker(f)^{\bot} \neq \{0\}$ there exist a $z \in ker(f)^{\bot}$ s.t $f(z) = 1$. Why can't we have a function which never passes the point $1$, and if it does why does $z$ need to be in $ker(f)^\bot$?

On the rest of the proof i understand the logic, if one is interested, this proof can be found in the book linear functional analysis of Bryanne P rynne and Martin A youngson on page 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mbox{ker}(f)^{\perp} \ne \{0\}$, then there exists $x \ne 0$ such that $x\perp\mbox{ker}(f)$. Then $f(x)\ne 0$ because, otherwise, $x\perp x$ would force $x=0$. Because $f(x)\ne 0$, then $f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}x\right)=1$.

Comment: very nice and $\frac{1}{f(x)} x$ is in this $\ker(f)^{\bot}$ since it is a linear subspace thank you :D

Comment: @KeesTil : You're welcome.